# Copy paste / Applying armature to mesh / Mirror modifier giving strange results *Possible bug?*

Tags: rigging, mirror

So I've been creating a few characters for an animation and I've encountered an issue I've never had in blender before, when either copy pasting a mesh from separate files, using the mirror modifier, or applying automatic weights to armatures the results are always dodgy.

The results are similar to if I hadn't applied transform, but I've already tried that and it hasn't worked.

Before applying auto weights when connecting armature to mesh:

[image]

After Connecting:

[image]

The mesh becomes displaced as if the global coordinates are off.

Same issue with mirroring and copy pasting objects across files

[image]
Rather stumped and it's stopping me from rigging my characters, any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a transforms issue to me. To avoid issues would make the scales of each mesh and armature unity (1, 1, 1) and  zero rotation.

Comment: Unforunately that's the thing I tried to do which didn't end up working, it might even turn out to be a bug since I've never seen anything like this

Comment: Perhaps a sample file or a screenshot with mesh object selected with object transform settings before what you call "connecting" will shed some light.